# Function for Get-ADUser in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm writing the below function in PowerShell and on execution an error is generated:

```
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'EmployeeId -eq ' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position
: '12'.
At line:14 char:16
```

The function is below.

```
Function UpdateGroupMembership ($Members, $Group, $err) {

$Members | ForEach-Object {
    $EID = $_.ID
    $filter = [scriptblock]::Create("EmployeeId -eq $EID")
    If ((Get-ADUser -Filter $filter) -like "") 
        {$err += "`n"+"User: "+$_."First Name"+" "+$_."Last Name"+" was not found in "+$_."District"+"<br>"} 
    Else 
        {$alias += Get-ADUser -Filter $filter}
}

$alias | ForEach-Object {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $_.SamAccountName
}
```

}

```
UpdateGroupMembership ($atl, $atlGroup, $atlerr)
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated! Just learning PowerShell...so please go easy on me!

Comment: Your code is difficult to read because it has no indenting. Formatting your code better would help those of us trying to help you. Also, you are inconsistent with how you write If/Else blocks. Also makes it harder to read.

Comment: Sorry about that....fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some understanding of and functions and parameters, as well as error handling is in order here. You leave out some info so I am going to assume that `$atl` is an array of objects, and that those objects each have (at least) the properties 'ID', 'First Name', and 'Last Name'. I assume that `$atlGroup` is a string being the name of the group you want to add the users defined in those objects to. I also assume that `$atlerr` is probably nothing, but that you want it to be populated with errors should they happen.

This really comes down to what Matt said in his answer. You are calling your function incorrectly. You are passing an array of objects as the first parameter (the 'Members' parameter). So here's the flow of the function as you have it...

```
$Members = @($atl, $atlGroup, $atlErr)
$Group = $null
$Err = $null
```

`$Members` then gets passed to a ForEach loop, so it passes it's first item, which is an array of objects. It passes the entire array of `$atl` on to the ForEach loop, so that loop now goes:

```
$EID = $atl.ID
```

Well, here we have a problem. $atl is an array, it doesn't have a property of 'ID' like all of the objects it contains. So it returns `$null`, so...

```
$EID = $null
$filter = [scriptblock]::Create("EmployeeId -eq $EID")
```

Ok, so now `$filter` is a scriptblock that looks like `{EmployeeId -eq $null}`, which as a scriptblock goes is just fine. The problem is that when it is passed to the Get-ADUser cmdlet as the argument for the `-Filter` parameter that parameter expects you to provide something in the format of:

```
Property Operator Value
```

You're looking at the EmployeeID property, and using the `-eq` operator. That property is a string, so it expects you to provide a string to compare it to. You don't do that, so it throws an error.

Now you were hoping to catch those errors with your If/Else statement, but son you're simply re-creating the wheel with that. PowerShell already has Try/Catch blocks, and here's how they work. If you `Try` an action that causes the script to stop, instead of stopping it moves to the `Catch` scriptblock and executes that.

So to simplify what you were doing we could `Try` to get the ad user, and pipe that directly into `add-adprincipalgroupmembership` (this cmdlet accepts piped in user objects, and lets you define the name of the group to add them to as opposed to the cmdlet that you used which accepted piped group objects and lets you define what users to add to the group). Then in the `Catch` block we output your error which should only happen when the process in the `Try` block fails. Now you just assign the output of the function to whatever you want to store your errors in. It ends up looking something like this:

```
Function UpdateGroupMembership{
Param(
    [object[]]$Members,
    [String]$Group
)

    ForEach($User in $Members){
        Try{
            Get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeId -eq "$($User.ID)"} | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $Group
        }
        Catch{
            "User: {0} {1} was not found." -f $User."First Name",$User."Last Name"
        } 
    }
}

$atlErr = UpdateGroupMembership $atl $atlGroup
```

Matt's answer really does answer your question, I just wanted to offer some guidance on how exactly the process was working and why you got the errors, and give some advise on how you could have better written the function so you have something to take with you going forward. I up-voted Matt's answer, it does answer the question, I just thought some additional context and help on fixing the issue would be in order to help out a newbie. We've all been there at some point.

**Edit:** I should also mention that I think creating a function to process groups of things like this is a mistake. You would be better served making it process one thing, and accepting piped input or putting it in a ForEach loop. But that's just my opinion, take it or leave it.

Comment: Thanks both of you....such detailed help is something that I couldn't even get from Microsoft support! Truly awesome!

@TheMadTechnician - your description of what I was trying is on the point exactly. I also appreciate the detailed explanation and now I understand the Try/Catch.

Comment: However when I try the block of code you mention....I don't think the Get-ADUser is returning any results and consequently the Add-ADPrincipal is not updating the group. Any thoughts?

Comment: $atl will have four colums - City, ID, Last Name, First Name

Comment: I think I figured it out....with some tinkering.

I modified the Try code block slightly since it doesn't look that any variable within the -Filter is getting evaluated. I just evaluated the filter separately and then passed that variable to the filter. Also removed the comma in the call to the function (last line)

Comment: You are right, and normally I actually sub-expression it like `{EmployeeID -eq "$($User.ID)"}` I don't know why I didn't here. Your work around should function the same though, so good on you. And yes, the comma in the last line is simply not right. I will edit my answer to correct those for future help seekers. Also, if your question was satisfactorily answered you should mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say exactly how your code works since you don't show us any input but the following is the first major issue

**Function Parameters**

```
UpdateGroupMembership ($atl, $atlGroup, $atlerr)
```

Functions are not methods. When you call your function like that you are sending all arguments as an array to the parameter `$Members`. The call has to look like this.

```
UpdateGroupMembership $atl, $atlGroup, $atlerr
```

**That `If` Block**

```
((Get-ADUser -Filter $filter) -like "")
```

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but `-like` is usually used for string comparisons. `Get-ADUser` would return an object array or `$null`. Are you testing to see if it is empty or null?

```
If(Get-ADUser -Filter $filter){

}
```

The above would only be true if data was returned.

**About `$err`**

Are you trying to pass back information through that variable? Function be default pass information by value so you populating `$err` would have no use outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Function UpdateGroupMembership {
Param(
    [object[]]$Members,
    [String]$Group
)

    ForEach($User in $Members){
        Try{
            $filter = $($User.ID)
            Get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeId -eq $filter} | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf $Group
        }
        Catch{
            "User: {0} {1} was not found in {2}." -f $User."First Name",$User."Last Name", $User.District
        } 
    }
}

$atlErr = UpdateGroupMembership $atl $atlGroup
```